# how to use readLines() in R

Tags: r, txt

I use readLines() in R to read a txt.file from ftp. The link is something like "ftp://ftp....". An error is reported like "URL status was 'URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL'".

The odd thing is that "ftp..." can be accessed when I directly type it in browser.

Sorry that I cannot type the whole link. I'm not sure if it's a version issue, since this code works before. Has anyone experience such an issue before?

Comment: You may need to send headers within a web request. Look up the multiple options in R. When you receive successful response, pass content into `readLines`.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for your answer. I'm new to this topic, could you please say it more on heads and web request.